# Use of the special power "Diplomat" against another player not yet entered the game in Smallworld

Tags: small-world

If you're playing a race with the special power "Diplomat" during the first round, are you allowed to declare peace with a player that has not yet entered the game?

Answer (score 2):

I found an [answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/8151/5056) to this question in an answer to a similar [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/8150/can-the-diplomat-power-be-used-against-a-player-without-an-active-race):

> **Q:** Is a race with the Diplomat power allowed to nominate a player, who has just declined or who has not yet had a turn (and therefore has no active race) as an ally?
>
> **A:** Yes indeed, the only restriction in the choice of an ally is that you cannot choose a player if you just attacked his active race.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. There is nothing in the rules to suggest that the race you choose needs to have units on the board.